$\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof, is this correct?
I tried to do an exercise on $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof for a limit. I'm not confident in myself, and I need hence your advice / hints / opinions / corrections.
$$\lim_{x\to 1} x^2+1 = 2$$
Well, using the definition, I started from the end, that is $|f(x) - \ell| < \epsilon$, that is $|(x^2+1)-2| < \epsilon$ and again $|x^2-1| < \epsilon$.
Then I did this:
$$|x^2-1| < \epsilon \iff |x-1||x+1| < \epsilon \iff |x-1| < \frac{\epsilon}{|x+1|}$$
Now when $x \to 1$ then $x+1 \to 2$ hence
$$|x-1| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
Since we also need $|x-1| < \delta$ we have to take $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.
Is this correct? If not, why?
Also: would it be better to say we take $\delta = \min\{1, \epsilon/2\}$? For example if we at the beginning chose to fix $\epsilon = 1$...

If you want to have $\varepsilon-\delta$ language, then you shouldn't use "$\to$".

@zkutch  Can you please explain me why? Should I use directly "$=$"?

The arrow doesn't mean anything in the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ language. You should instead write $|x-1|<\delta$.

Regarding the last question: You are not allowed to put any restrictions on $\epsilon$ like fixing $\epsilon=1.$ You are however allowed to put upper bounds on $\delta$ which is what you do if you take $\delta=\min(1, \epsilon/2).$

"Now when x→1 then x+1→2
hence
|x−1|<ϵ2"  I think you need to understand what this means. If $x=0$ then $\frac {\epsilon}{|x+1|}\not < \frac \epsilon 2$.  If $x=0.9999$ then $\frac {\epsilon}{|x+1|}\not < \frac \epsilon 2$.   Do you understand what a delta epsilon proof is trying to do?

It is hard to say whether it is correct or not, because it is not clear which meaning you attach to “when $x\to1$ then $x+1\to2$” or whether or  not what you wrote next is compatible with that meaning.
Here is how I would do it. Take $\varepsilon>0$. If $|x-1|<1$, then $0<x<2$, and therefore $1+<x+1<3$; in particular, $|x+1|<3$, and therefore$$|x^2-1|=|x-1|\times|x+1|<3|x-1|.$$So, take $\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac\varepsilon3\right\}$. Then, if $|x-1|<\delta$, you have both $|x-1|<1$ and $|x-1|<\frac\varepsilon3$, and therefore$$|x^2-1|<3|x-1|<3\times\frac\varepsilon3=\varepsilon.$$So,$$|x-1|<\delta\implies|x^2+1-2|<\varepsilon.$$

I don’t think the first statement is ‘meaningless’, it would be correct to say x+1 tends to 2 as x tends to 1 and most people would read it as basically saying that

And what does that mean?

The statement certainly isn't "meaningless".  It has a fairly standard interpretation:  "when $x\to 1$, then $x+1\to 2$" means "for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that $|x-1|< \delta$ implies that $|(x+1)-2| < \varepsilon$.  Or, in other words, $\lim_{x\to 1} (x+1) = 2$.  The grammar of the statement might be a little off, but the meaning is perfectly clear.

@XanderHenderson What you called a fairly standard interpretation is the usual interpretation of the equality $\lim_{x\to1}x+1=2$. Anyway, even assuming that “when $x\to1$ then $x+1\to2$” means what you wrote, I see no sign that the OP saw it like that. After all, after writing that expression the OP wrote “hence $|x-1|<\frac\varepsilon2$”, with no $\delta$ involved.

Yes, I agree that the asker is confused.  And they may not know or understand what they, themselves wrote.  But to claim that "when $x\to 1$, then $x+1\to 2$" is meaningless is, in my opinion, needlessly denigrating.  I know many competent mathematicians who happy write things like "observe that $x+1\to 2$ as $x\to 1$" (which is essentially the same statement).  Like I said, the grammar is a bit off, but I think that the sentence is perfectly clear, and certainly not meaningless.

@XanderHenderson I have edited my first sentence. What do you think now?

Thank you for this. How did you come up with $|x-1| < 1$? Did you choose $\delta = 1$ randomly?

A bit, yes. Imagine that I had started with $|x-1|<\frac12$. Then, by the same approach, I would have deduced that $|x+1|<\frac52$ and that therefore $|x^2-1|<\frac52|x-1|$, which would have led me to $\delta=\min\left{\frac32,\frac{2\varepsilon}5\right}$. But starting with $1$ is the simpler choice.

It’s a little confused. I would never advise writing the proof by starting “from the end” even if that’s how you actually think of the proof.
I agree with comment don’t use —> if the whole idea is to write an epsilons proof.
A cleaner way overall would be to go via
$$
|x^2-1| = |(x-1+1)^2 -1| \\
= |(x-1)^2 + 2(x-1)| \\
\leq |x-1|^2 +2|x-1|.
$$

When you say "if $x\to 1$, then $x+1 \to 2$", then it is same with $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}(x+1)=2$. This gives, that you are using $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}x=1$. So you are using $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}x^2=1$ in proof of $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}x^2+1=2$.
You get a proof of the cyclic type, where you use a proposition to prove itself. And in addition, the purity of the proof by a method $\varepsilon-\delta$ is lost, because it  assumes that the reasoning is carried out at a level below the using of the limit, i.e. at the level of definition of the limit.
